# Haskell Cabal+Nix: Generate local documentation for all dependencies in a project

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

How can I generate documentation, possibly with a local `hoogle` server, with cabal and nix?

I know there is a `cabal new-haddock` command, but it throws an error:

```
cabal: renderBuildTargetProblem: unexpected status (TargetDisabledByUser,Nothing)
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at ./Distribution/Client/CmdErrorMessages.hs:329:14 in main:Distribution.Client.CmdErrorMessages
```

And it seems like it is used to build documentation of my project, not of my dependencies anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out all documentation is already there in the `/nix/store/`.
All I needed to do was to generate local documentation with `hoogle` like so:

```
hoogle generate --local --database project.hoo
```

Then start a server with:

```
hoogle server --local -p 8080
```

And now everything is statically linked. Done!